# Understanding Auth::routes() after php artisan make:auth

Tags: laravel-5.3

Laravel provides with register controller and Auth::routes() defines the use of this controller. I went to auth() function in Router.php and found that upon registration route calls register function in register controller,

```
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

but I cannot find this register function in RegisterController file. What is happening here ? Am I missing something? I am new to laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RegisterController` uses a trait named `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers` in which you will find your `register()` method.

Check out in the Laravel's source code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cfcb04eaed9cd2189cbbae4dea39d26db70249d7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php#L29).

Read more about trait [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).